If a cell contains specific text return a number in another cell and increment that number for other cells in the column
This is probably quite simple but I can't seem to get it to work exactly how I want it to.
I have a table in Excel which has new entries added to it in new table rows AT THE TOP of the table.  In column B for each row I want the cell to generate a number based on specific text in the cell in column A.  In the example below, I want to only return the number if the text is "APPLE".  Example:
Table 1



A
B




APPLE
0005


APPLE
0004


APPLE
0003


APPLE
0002


PEAR



APPLE
0001



I've had some success with this formula:
=IF(A1="APPLE",COUNTA($B$1:B1),"")

However this produces:
Table 2



A
B




APPLE
0006


APPLE
0005


APPLE
0004


APPLE
0003


PEAR



APPLE
0001



It correctly ignores "PEAR" however the cell above still considers it in it's sequence.  How can I adjust the formula or if there is a better formula, so it outputs as per "Table 1" please?  Thanks in advance for your help!

I found an answer that works!
=IF(A6="APPLE",COUNTIF(A$6:A6,"APPLE"),"")

